# How to convert a script from youtube-dl

Tags: cmd, ffmpeg, youtube-dl

There is a bash/batch file script:

```bat
ffmpeg -i `youtube-dl https://www.twitch.tv/zero` -vf fps=fps=60, scale=1920x1080 -c:v libx264 -b:v 500k -preset superfast -c:a copy -f segment -segment_time 60 test.mp4
```

The script is not mine, but it allows you to record video with a constant frame rate of parts. Unfortunately in cmd it does not work for me. Already tried everything, I do not know what the error is.

I am getting `No such file or directory`.

Tried `'youtube-dl https://www.twitch.tv/zero'`, the same error

I tried `"youtube-dl https://www.twitch.tv/zero"`, error: `youtube-dl https://www.twitch.tv/zero: Invalid argument`

What am I doing wrong? The author assures that he works on linux

**Update**

I tried `ffmpeg -i $ (youtube-dl -f best -g https://www.twitch.tv/zero) ....` The same error

**Update 2**

Why the video size exceeds 500 Mb? What am I doing wrong?

[image]
[image]

**Code**

```bat
cls && @echo off & setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion 
set "_tag_00=https://www.twitch.tv/avagg"
set "_tag_01=--ignore-errors --abort-on-error --ignore-config --flat-playlist --geo-bypass "
set "_tag_02=--restrict-filenames --no-part --no-cache-dir --write-thumbnail --prefer-ffmpeg "
set "_tag_03=--ffmpeg-location .\ --postprocessor-args  -i "%%(title)s.%%(ext)s" -vf fps^=fps^=60^,"
set "_tag_04=scale^=1920x1080 -c:v libx264 -b:v 500k -preset superfast -c:a copy -f segment -segment_time "
set "_tag_05=60 %%^(title^)s.mp4"

youtube-dl "!_tag_00!" -f "bestvideo[ext=mp4]+bestaudio[ext=m4a]/best[ext=mp4]/best" -o "%%^(title^)s.%%^(ext^)s" !_tag_1!!_tag_2!!_tag_3!!_tag_4!!_tag_5!
Pause
```

**Update 3**

[image]

Comment: The youtube-dl main error: No such file or directory

Comment: you have problem on parsing arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, pay **attention** to **some points** below:

- So, if I really understand your question, and it is about batch file/cmd in Windows, you **would need to put** the path to **`ffmpeg.exe`** in a variable, so it can be accessible to `youtube-dl` found it.
- Or, in my sample above, in same path and in variable argument tool, so, youtube-dl amd `ffmepg.exe` are in same folder/path = `.\\`.
- The link in this [question](https://www.twitch.tv/zero), is **offline**, so I changed this link to an another [online](https://www.twitch.tv/playhearthstone): 
  [image: cmd output]

I’ll save this code by name **`yt-DL.cmd`**

**Copy only a specific time by:**   Only edit **`_tag_1`** value: **`-t 00:60:00`**

```bat
   cls && @echo off & setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion 

    :: do some with the bat file, after then,  for all links need `call :_yd_dl` %1

    call :_yd_dl %1
    echo/ is done^^!!

    goto :eof

    :_yd_dl

    set "_tag_00=%1"
    set "_tag_01= -t 00:60:00 -v error -stats -vf fps=fps=60,scale=1920x1080 -c:v libx264 -preset superfast -c:a copy "
    for /f %%i in ('.\youtube-dl.exe -g !_tag_00! ^<nul ') do .\ffmpeg.exe  -i "%%i" !_tag_01! .\output.mp4

    exit /b
```

**copy full video by:**

```bat
  cls && @echo off & setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion 

    :: do some with the bat file, after then,  for all links need `call :_yd_dl` %1

    call :_yd_dl %1
    echo/ is done^^!!

    goto :eof

    :_yd_dl

    set "_tag_0=%1"
    set "_tag_1=--ignore-errors --abort-on-error --ignore-config --flat-playlist --geo-bypass "
    set "_tag_2=--restrict-filenames --no-part --no-cache-dir --write-thumbnail --prefer-ffmpeg "
    set "_tag_3=--ffmpeg-location .\ --postprocessor-args  -i "%%(title)s.%%(ext)s" -vf fps^=fps^=60^,"
    set "_tag_4=scale^=1920x1080 -c:v libx264 -b:v 500k -preset superfast -c:a copy -f segment -segment_time "
    set "_tag_5=60 %%^(title^)s.mp4"

    youtube-dl "!_tag_0!" -f "bestvideo[ext=mp4]+bestaudio[ext=m4a]/best[ext=mp4]/best" -o "%%^(title^)s.%%^(ext^)s" !_tag_1!!_tag_2!!_tag_3!!_tag_4!!_tag_5!

    exit /b
```

Comment: I wanted to mount video parts during recording, but with such a load on the intel i7 - 4700 2.4Ghz x 8 thread, you can forget about editing. It will be easier to write a python script using Selenium Webdriver (any browser) + Bandicam (there is already encoding and splitting into parts) and the load will be less

Comment: I'm sorry, I did not understand you. Which list?

Comment: Something I do not understand anything at all. You want to transfer the cycle to a text document in order not to burden the CPU with a check?

Comment: I propose to close the topic, as it prevents us from understanding each other's language barrier.