# How can I make batchfile repeats the command until the video I want to download with youtube-dl is LIVE?

Tags: loops, batch-file, youtube-dl

I want to use youtube-dl which is based on commands and has to be opened via CMD.
The problem is I want to download live broadcasts and they always starts under same URL, which I can paste in my batch file.
What I want to achieve is to be make the batchfile repeat the command `cmd /K "E:\YouTube\youtube-dl.exe -f best [URL]"` (which opens the .exe file with `-f best [URL]`) until the video is possible to download.

Currently, I've got only batch file with that:

```
cmd /K "E:\YouTube\youtube-dl.exe -f best [URL]"
```

When the live broadcast is offline it says *"ERROR: Video is unavailable"*, so I want to make the batch repeat this command until the broadcast goes live and I'll be able to download it immediately.

Would it be possible to, for instance, make something like this:
if the response for `cmd /K "E:\YouTube\youtube-dl.exe -f best [URL]"` is `"ERROR: Video is unavailable"` then repeat it?

I'm not really experienced in those matters, so I have no clue what to look for.

Comment: You might be able to use an `if "%errorlevel%"=="1" (goto start)` but I'm not completly sure on how the youtube api works. Another option is to check the output for if it contains `ERROR:` and have it go back to retry the command.

Answer (score 0):

> *So, if I understand your question...*

1) *You need take **[ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/win64/static/ffmpeg-20190124-3224d66-win64-static.zip)** for make the stream downloading.*

2) *Please, put the* **`ffmpeg.exe`** *+* **`youtube-dl.exe`** *and also, the* **`file.bat`** *in same folder*

> *Also, please, fill free to see this answer about live stream with ffmpeg + youtube-dl live transcoding* **[download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53804437/how-to-convert-a-script-from-youtube-dl/53805286#53805286)**

And, so sorry my limited English.

```bat
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 

:: for work, you need to set manually the variable _link : 

set _link=your link add here 

:: or, use argument command line to parse the link: 

if ".\%~1/." neq ".\/." set "_link=%~1"

:_loop

call :_yd_dl && echo/ Downloading is done^^!!

goto :eof

:_yd_dl

youtube-dl "!_link!" -f "bestvideo[ext=mp4]+bestaudio[ext=m4a]/best[ext=mp4]/best" -o "%%^(title^)s.%%^(ext^)s" 
if not !errorlevel! == 0 goto :_loop

exit /b
```